# DOMDocument -> unable to pull results from href

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have been able to pull the html of a given node

```
<td class="winner">
                <a href="/jockey/497-g-lee">G Lee</a><br><em><a href="/trainer/3372-r-varian">R Varian </a></em>
            </td>
```

what im trying to do is pull the text if href contains jockey (in this case the result will be G Lee).

im doing this by doing the following

```
@$dom2->loadHTML($trainer);
$xpath2 = new DOMXPath($dom2);
//chekc to see if it had html in it?


$result_rows2 = $xpath2->query('//a[contains(@href, "jockey")]');
```

note trainer is just the html posted above.

now i do a var_dump on the data and get this:

```
object(DOMNodeList)#12 (1) { ["length"]=> int(1) } object(DOMNodeList)#13 (1) { ["length"]=> int(1) } object(DOMNodeList)#12 (1) { ["length"]=> int(1) } object(DOMNodeList)#13 (1) { ["length"]=> int(1) } object(DOMNodeList)#12 (1) { ["length"]=> int(1) } object(DOMNodeList)#13 (1) { ["length"]=> int(1) } object(DOMNodeList)#12 (1) { ["length"]=> int(1) } im not sure why but its not picking up the results?!?!?
```

would anyone be able to assist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your var_dump is showing that there is one item found by the XPath (length = 1), so try to access it:

```
echo $result_rows2->item(0)->textContent;
```

Outputting DOMNodeLists and other objects don't always show their full internal structure when using `print_r` and `var_dump` etc, but your data is there.

[Working Codepad demo](http://codepad.org/E748diiw)